# Documentation system which is independent of programming language

Tags: documentation-generation

Is there a documentation system which is simple, will generate some friendly, hyperlinked documentation, for **any** language through the use of comment indications? Such a system may merely be given regexes or patterns to recognise comments and then generate structure.

I was going to write one but figured there *must* be one already.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'd imagine rexeps would rapidly border on insane to support the allowed commenting schemes used in many languages. Then you've got the problem of making damn sure you don't match actual code anywhere... fun problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/)? It may be what you're looking for.

Comment: first line on page: "Doxygen is a documentation system for C++, C, Java, Objective-C, Python, IDL (Corba and Microsoft flavors), Fortran, VHDL, PHP, C#, and to some extent D."